# How to extract the substring array in shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to extract the substring array using `cut` option in shell script but it is not extracting correctly. I used the below code to extract the substring array.

```
myval="one two three four"
mysubstr=$(echo $myval| cut -d' ' -f 1,2,3,4)
echo "${mysubstr[1]}"
```

`mysubstr` is printing empty value now.

Comment: `mysubstr` is not an array at all. It's just a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
$ myval="one two three four"
$ mysubstr=($myval)
$ for i in ${mysubstr[@]}; do echo $i; done
one
two
three
four
```